# Let last column in a bootstrap row take up rest of viewport width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to create a layout section on a site which uses Twitter bootstrap grid.

I need a regular `.container` with a `col-xs-3` column and then the next column should simply fill the rest of the browser viewport. The content of the large "full width" column should fill the div all the way to the right side of the browser.

While I do realise that this is violating the rules of the grid, it's important for me, that the first col (`.col-xs-3`) uses the exact same left position as all other columns to keep content aligned horizontally.

See drawing for clarification:

[image]

I'm absolutely open to suggestions of doing this without using the boostrap grid in the middle section, but still, it's important the left position from tablet and up.

Any suggestions? :-)

**EDIT:**

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="product-slideshow">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 categories">
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Product 1</a></li>
                    <li><a>Product 2</a></li>
                    <li><a>Product 3</a></li>
                    <li><a>Product 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- This column should span all the way to the right side of the browser -->
            <div class="col-xs-9 images">
                <div class="slider-wrapper">
                    <img class="slide" src="..." />
                    <img class="slide" src="..." />
                    <img class="slide" src="..." />
                    <img class="slide" src="..." />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Actually managed to fix this meanwhile. I'm using [Slick.js slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) for the slideshow/content in the large column, and appearantly, the following CSS (SASS) did the trick:

```
.products-slideshow {
    overflow-x: hidden;

    .images {
        position: relative;

        .slider-wrapper {
            max-width: calc(100vw - 25%); // 25% being the col-xs-3 width
            position: absolute;
            height: auto;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my question, since I wasn't clear about what the full width column should actually be used for. The questions marked as similar doesn't fully utilise the rest of the viewport for actual content.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you've tried so far.. such as the basic column layout.

Comment: Read about the gutter in bootstrap first select the div col-xs-9 then you will have 20px margin right and may be .row will help you doing this task

Answer (score 4):

If i truly understand you, you can use flexbox:

```
.row{
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;      
 }

 .col-xs-9{
   flex: 1;
 }
```

The div with `flex: 1` will fill the remained space of the container, in flex direction (in this case row).